# Do empty transforms take up much CPU power?

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, loading, instantiation

So long story short, I'm developing a game for Mobile set in a city and there are a lot of objects being brought in and out of play as the player moves about.

I have tried numerous methods for seamlessly loading in/out objects.

First I tried instantiating and destroying objects for loading/unloading. This had noticeable spikes for even loading in something simple like a generic 3D box.

Second attempt, I put the Instantiating/Destroying calls into their own Coroutines, this made the spikes less severe, but they were still noticeable.

Thirdly, I decided to pre-instantiate all the objects I'd need and then keep all the ones not in play as deactive (SetActive(false)). It turns out that setting active to true (even done inside a coroutine) had worse performance than instantiating the objects.

So, I finally arrived at my last idea for loading. I preloaded all the needed objects, then manually went through each one's children, disabling each component that could use up CPU. Such components as scripts, renderers, colliders, audio sources, particle systems, rigidbody (set to isKinematic = true) etc were all disabled, leaving only an object with children transforms. Now I can finally enable an object (enable all its components) and the game has no spikes in performance.

However, this last solution has its own draw back. If I preload too many objects the games FPS will be significantly impacted. Event though there is nothing enabled inside the object besides its transforms.

So my question is, does having many transforms (non moving) in the scene cause a significant hit to the CPU usage? and, If so, what is the best way to do continuous loading/unloading of game objects for Mobile?

Comment: I'm surprised that toggling pre-instantiated objects was slower than instantiating, sounds to me like you are doing something wrong, as object pooling is usually the correct solution to this problem. Try reading https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling and http://unitypatterns.com/resource/objectpool and see if you've missed something.

Comment: Do you have any warnings or errors in your console window? Possibly anything about moving static objects? If you can, have you tried running your project through the profiler to find performance hot spots?

Comment: How many transforms cause the problem? Also, non moving transforms aren't helping much if they're not marked as static - try that.

Comment: **yoyo**: Yeah I was surprised by that as well. To clarify, Instantiating an gameobject **from within a coroutine** has less noticeable jitter than calling SetActive(true) on a pre-instantiated gameobject (also within a coroutine). But SetActive(true) is faster when both are outside of a coroutine. To clarify, I meant that gameobjects in an idle/disabled state (not in gameplay) are stationary/not-moving. They may move when brought back into play, thus they can't be set as static.

Comment: **ChanibaL**: So my game is for mobile and I have about 1000-1500 transforms (on pre-loaded prefabs) that are just sitting idly outside of gameplay (all components disabled, and rigidbodies set to isKinematic=true). When brought into play these objects might be moving around (people, cars, etc), thus they cannot be set to static.

Comment: Are these 1500 objects clones of each other? Have you tried using the [Object Pool Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_pool_pattern) on them? I wouldn't recommend that you instantiate and destroy your objects again and again. Object Pooling will help you out if you have cloned objects. Apart from that, empty transforms don't take up any CPU power compared to what goes in calculating other parts of the program. Also, why not put your game in multiple scenes as you see fit and load them asynchronously with the LoadLevelAsync method? Its available in Unity 5 Personal Edition now for use.

Comment: Also, if you have game object that has collider attached to it, and your scripts are moving it, then you MUST put a rigid body component to it. If you don't want Physics engine to apply its behaviour on the rigid body, then simply make the object Kinematic.

Comment: Hey Aman, thanks for the responses. So I never got to the bottom of exactly why the pooled unenabled objects were causing such a performance issue. But I did come up with a pretty comprehensive system of slowly loading/unloading objects with no hit to the performance. I simply run through each child and deactive/active it iteratively within a coroutine. Thus there are never a bunch of transforms etc being activated at once on the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

Use a component called lod group. You can set then your low poly models and it will unable and enable the mesh renderers according with the distance of your camera.